# missing .bash_history

Tags: bash, history, bash-history

I cant find `.bash_history` file in my home directory. I do:

```
echo $HISTFILE
/home/myname/.bash_history
```

But if I try to list the file with `ls`, I get:

```
$ ls -l ~/.bash_history
ls: cannot access /home/myname/.bash_history: No such file or directory
```

If I run the `history` command, however, all history commands are listed.

So, why I can't see `.bash_history` file?

Comment: Is the history shown if you open a new terminal and run `history`? Please [edit] your question and post the output of `ls -l ~/.bash_history` (just to be sure).

Comment: got:  ls: cannot access /home/myname/.bash_history: No such file or directory

Comment: in new terminal history is missing

Comment: Ah, there you go. You've deleted the file, apparently. Your current terminal still has it in memory but a new one doesn't so `history` returns nothing. I'm voting to close this since it is unlikely to help anyone else.